# Crash report are not coming in with Aralyzer

Tags: java, android, crash-reports, acra, acralyzer

I have set up Acralyzer on my application, but the reports are not coming in. The last report came about 10 days ago, but now no reports are coming. I don't really know much about acralyzer, but after researching I was able to set it up like this. Please the log shows that the message was successful, cos I don't really understand the logs

```
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    CoreConfigurationBuilder builder = new CoreConfigurationBuilder(this)
            .setBuildConfigClass(BuildConfig.class)
            .setReportFormat(StringFormat.JSON);
    builder.getPluginConfigurationBuilder(HttpSenderConfigurationBuilder.class)
            .setUri("*******")
            .setHttpMethod(HttpSender.Method.PUT)
            .setBasicAuthLogin("******")
            .setBasicAuthPassword("*********")
            .setEnabled(true);
    builder.getPluginConfigurationBuilder(SchedulerConfigurationBuilder.class)
            .setRequiresNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
            .setEnabled(true);
    ACRA.DEV_LOGGING = true;
    ACRA.init(this, builder);
}
```

This is what I get from the logs

````
2022-09-09 06:44:51.154 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Using default Report Fields
2022-09-09 06:44:51.159 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: ACRA processName=''
2022-09-09 06:44:51.166 7476-7476/ I/ACRA: ACRA is enabled for , initializing...
2022-09-09 06:44:51.169 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: ServicePluginLoader loading services from ServiceLoader : java.util.ServiceLoader[org.acra.collector.Collector]
2022-09-09 06:44:51.179 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Loaded Collector of type org.acra.collector.ConfigurationCollector
2022-09-09 06:44:51.179 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Loaded Collector of type org.acra.collector.CustomDataCollector
2022-09-09 06:44:51.180 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Loaded Collector of type org.acra.collector.DeviceFeaturesCollector
2022-09-09 06:44:51.181 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Loaded Collector of type org.acra.collector.DeviceIdCollector
2022-09-09 06:44:51.183 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Loaded Collector of type org.acra.collector.DisplayManagerCollector
2022-09-09 06:44:51.185 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Loaded Collector of type org.acra.collector.DropBoxCollector
2022-09-09 06:44:51.187 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Loaded Collector of type org.acra.collector.LogCatCollector
2022-09-09 06:44:51.188 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Loaded Collector of type org.acra.collector.LogFileCollector
2022-09-09 06:44:51.190 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Loaded Collector of type org.acra.collector.MediaCodecListCollector
2022-09-09 06:44:51.192 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Loaded Collector of type org.acra.collector.MemoryInfoCollector
2022-09-09 06:44:51.192 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Loaded Collector of type org.acra.collector.PackageManagerCollector
2022-09-09 06:44:51.193 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Loaded Collector of type org.acra.collector.ReflectionCollector
2022-09-09 06:44:51.195 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Loaded Collector of type org.acra.collector.SettingsCollector
2022-09-09 06:44:51.196 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Loaded Collector of type org.acra.collector.SharedPreferencesCollector
2022-09-09 06:44:51.197 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Loaded Collector of type org.acra.collector.SimpleValuesCollector
2022-09-09 06:44:51.198 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Loaded Collector of type org.acra.collector.StacktraceCollector
2022-09-09 06:44:51.199 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Loaded Collector of type org.acra.collector.ThreadCollector
2022-09-09 06:44:51.219 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Loaded Collector of type org.acra.collector.TimeCollector
2022-09-09 06:44:51.230 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: ServicePluginLoader loading services from ServiceLoader : java.util.ServiceLoader[org.acra.scheduler.SenderSchedulerFactory]
2022-09-09 06:44:51.236 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Checking plugin Configurations : ImmutableList{[org.acra.config.HttpSenderConfiguration@8a7fa5a, org.acra.config.SchedulerConfiguration@969348b]} for class : class org.acra.config.SchedulerConfiguration
2022-09-09 06:44:51.236 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Checking plugin Configuration : org.acra.config.HttpSenderConfiguration@8a7fa5a against plugin class : class org.acra.config.SchedulerConfiguration
2022-09-09 06:44:51.237 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Checking plugin Configuration : org.acra.config.SchedulerConfiguration@969348b against plugin class : class org.acra.config.SchedulerConfiguration
2022-09-09 06:44:51.237 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Ignoring disabled SenderSchedulerFactory of type Factory
2022-09-09 06:44:51.239 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: ServicePluginLoader loading services from ServiceLoader : java.util.ServiceLoader[org.acra.config.ReportingAdministrator]
2022-09-09 06:44:51.245 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Checking plugin Configurations : ImmutableList{[org.acra.config.HttpSenderConfiguration@8a7fa5a, org.acra.config.SchedulerConfiguration@969348b]} for class : class org.acra.config.SchedulerConfiguration
2022-09-09 06:44:51.245 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Checking plugin Configuration : org.acra.config.HttpSenderConfiguration@8a7fa5a against plugin class : class org.acra.config.SchedulerConfiguration
2022-09-09 06:44:51.245 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Checking plugin Configuration : org.acra.config.SchedulerConfiguration@969348b against plugin class : class org.acra.config.SchedulerConfiguration
2022-09-09 06:44:51.245 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: Ignoring disabled ReportingAdministrator of type RestartingAdministrator
2022-09-09 06:44:51.803 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: onActivityCreated class com.seamfix.nimc.activities.ExceptionHandlerActivity
2022-09-09 06:44:51.864 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: onActivityStarted class com.seamfix.nimc.activities.ExceptionHandlerActivity
2022-09-09 06:44:51.917 7476-7476/ D/ACRA: onActivityResumed class com.seamfix.nimc.activities.ExceptionHandlerActivity
2022-09-09 06:44:52.164 7476-7523/ D/ACRA: ServicePluginLoader loading services from ServiceLoader : java.util.ServiceLoader[org.acra.startup.StartupProcessor]
2022-09-09 06:44:52.170 7476-7523/ D/ACRA: Loaded StartupProcessor of type org.acra.startup.UnapprovedStartupProcessor
2022-09-09 06:44:52.428 7476-7523/ D/ACRA: Schedule report sending
2022-09-09 06:44:52.497 7476-7523/ D/ACRA: config#reportSenderFactoryClasses : ImmutableList{[]}
2022-09-09 06:44:52.497 7476-7523/ D/ACRA: Using PluginLoader to find ReportSender factories
2022-09-09 06:44:52.497 7476-7523/ D/ACRA: ServicePluginLoader loading services from ServiceLoader : java.util.ServiceLoader[org.acra.sender.ReportSenderFactory]
2022-09-09 06:44:52.503 7476-7523/ D/ACRA: Checking plugin Configurations : ImmutableList{[org.acra.config.HttpSenderConfiguration@8a7fa5a, org.acra.config.SchedulerConfiguration@969348b]} for class : class org.acra.config.HttpSenderConfiguration
2022-09-09 06:44:52.504 7476-7523/ D/ACRA: Checking plugin Configuration : org.acra.config.HttpSenderConfiguration@8a7fa5a against plugin class : class org.acra.config.HttpSenderConfiguration
2022-09-09 06:44:52.504 7476-7523/ D/ACRA: Loaded ReportSenderFactory of type org.acra.sender.HttpSenderFactory
2022-09-09 06:44:52.504 7476-7523/ D/ACRA: reportSenderFactories : [org.acra.sender.HttpSenderFactory@9cb2a17]
2022-09-09 06:44:52.506 7476-7523/ D/ACRA: Checking plugin Configurations : ImmutableList{[org.acra.config.HttpSenderConfiguration@8a7fa5a, org.acra.config.SchedulerConfiguration@969348b]} for class : class org.acra.config.HttpSenderConfiguration
2022-09-09 06:44:52.507 7476-7523/ D/ACRA: Checking plugin Configuration : org.acra.config.HttpSenderConfiguration@8a7fa5a against plugin class : class org.acra.config.HttpSenderConfiguration
2022-09-09 06:44:52.507 7476-7523/ D/ACRA: Adding reportSender : org.acra.sender.HttpSender@71e1e04
2022-09-09 06:44:52.517 7476-7523/ D/ACRA: config#reportSenderFactoryClasses : ImmutableList{[]}
2022-09-09 06:44:52.517 7476-7523/ D/ACRA: Using PluginLoader to find ReportSender factories
2022-09-09 06:44:52.517 7476-7523/ D/ACRA: ServicePluginLoader loading services from ServiceLoader : java.util.ServiceLoader[org.acra.sender.ReportSenderFactory]
2022-09-09 06:44:52.522 7476-7523/ D/ACRA: Checking plugin Configurations : ImmutableList{[org.acra.config.HttpSenderConfiguration@8a7fa5a, org.acra.config.SchedulerConfiguration@969348b]} for class : class org.acra.config.HttpSenderConfiguration
2022-09-09 06:44:52.522 7476-7523/ D/ACRA: Checking plugin Configuration : org.acra.config.HttpSenderConfiguration@8a7fa5a against plugin class : class org.acra.config.HttpSenderConfiguration
2022-09-09 06:44:52.522 7476-7523/ D/ACRA: Loaded ReportSenderFactory of type org.acra.sender.HttpSenderFactory
2022-09-09 06:44:52.522 7476-7523/ D/ACRA: reportSenderFactories : [org.acra.sender.HttpSenderFactory@54e50b3]
2022-09-09 06:44:52.523 7476-7523/ D/ACRA: Checking plugin Configurations : ImmutableList{[org.acra.config.HttpSenderConfiguration@8a7fa5a, org.acra.config.SchedulerConfiguration@969348b]} for class : class org.acra.config.HttpSenderConfiguration
2022-09-09 06:44:52.523 7476-7523/ D/ACRA: Checking plugin Configuration : org.acra.config.HttpSenderConfiguration@8a7fa5a against plugin class : class org.acra.config.HttpSenderConfiguration
2022-09-09 06:44:52.523 7476-7523/ D/ACRA: Adding reportSender : org.acra.sender.HttpSender@c611670```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [debugging guide](https://acra.ch/docs/How-to-debug) to figure out what is going wrong on your device. It's probably not a server side issue.

Comment: I tried POST still did not work. I should be able to SUCCESS on the logcat if the report was sent successfully right? I justed to be sure it's not an issue with the server

Comment: http://www.acra.ch/docs/How-to-debug

Comment: Thanks, @F43nd1r I was able to resolve it, it was an issue with my device, I guess it's because my device can't handle the job scheduler. Just a follow-up question. Can ACRA report a native app crash? Because I had an app crash but I didn't get the report neither was it showing on the logcat

Comment: http://www.acra.ch/docs/AdvancedUsage#catching-native-code-errors in short: not supported